# Using Materialize Gem for Rails and Submit Button on Form only works randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

So I have a form that is working when I don't use Materialize to stylize it. It submits and the info is saved into the database, but the problem arises when I use materialize to stylize the button. It randomly saves the data into the database when it is using the materialize styling(e.g. like 7 times in a row and then it stops and will randomly start working again). Is there a known error with this gem or am I missing something?

```
gem 'materialize-sass'
```

View

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
 <div class="action btn waves-effect waves-light actions">
<%= f.submit "Create my account" %>
</div>


 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your styling. In your example button will always work when you click on button caption only.

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
```